# J2ME Polish FramedForm Commands

Tags: forms, java-me, command, j2mepolish

I'm developing an application with J2ME Polish using a FramedForm.

I'm trying to append an item associated with a Command1 to the FramedForm and another item associated with a Command2 to the bottom of the FramedForm.

```
FramedForm menuForm = new FramedForm("Menu");

Command command1 = new Command("command1", Command.ITEM, 1);
Command command2 = new Command("command2", Command.ITEM, 2);

IconCustomItem item1 = new IconCustomItem("test1", null);
item1.addCommand(Command1);
menuForm.append(item1);

IconCustomItem item2 = new IconCustomItem("test2", null);
item2.addCommand(Command2);
menuForm.append(Graphics.BOTTOM, item2);
```

The problem is that the footer item is associated with both commands. I've tried using removeCommands() with no success. How can I associate the footer item only to the Command2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem [focusing the bottom frame](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/design/visual-guide/gui-screen-framedform.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default command to each item, instead of adding a single command.
Like:

```
item1.setDefaultCommand( command1 );
```

[See](http://www1.j2mepolish.org/javadoc/j2me/index.html) for more info for commands on Items:

Comment: The same happens when I use setDefaultCommand instead of addCommand.